# How to get pointcloud2 data from usb_cam or Pointgrey camera?

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, ar-track-alvar, camera, usb-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, experts~
I am a new in ROS. And recently, I am trying to get image and make it detected by the node ar_track_alvar. However, this ar node requires sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 data. Firstly I tried to use usb_cam_node and I got sensor_msgs/Image. The same situation happened using Pointgrey camera with its driver: pointgrey_camera_driver.
After searching some files, I find that it might work if I can use openni to get the image, after all it is discribed in wiki: "**Launch files to open an OpenNI device and load all nodelets to convert raw depth/RGB/IR streams to depth images, disparity images, and (registered) point clouds.**"[here](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch).  And after I run the command: " roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch " it says there is no device. I really don't know how to make it out. Can anyone help me answer the following question:

1. Can pointgrey camera be directly used by openni launch file?
2. Can common USB camera be used by openni launch?
3. If the answer of both is negative, how can I get pointcloud2 data with what kind of device and with which driver?
   P.S.
   Here is what shell says after I run *roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch*
   [ INFO] [1431337093.836048605]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: std::string openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Driver::resolveDeviceURI(const string&) @ /tmp/buildd/ros-indigo-openni2-camera-0.2.3-0trusty-20150327-0611/src/openni2_driver.cpp @ 623 : Invalid device number 1, there are 0 devices connected.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208960/how-to-get-pointcloud2-data-from-usb_cam-or-pointgrey-camera?/) by [david059](https://answers.ros.org/users/22144/david059/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For using openni package and also for generating point cloud you should have Kinect or Asus Xtion ( Depth Sensor). OpenNI wont work with normal usb camera. `usb_cam` package is to capture rgb image using usb camera.

For generating `pointcloud` u can use either Kinect with freenect package or rgbdslam ( available for electric Older version of ROS)

If you are only interested in creating 3D, you can use `lsd_slam or ORB slam`, it will give nice 3d in real time but it wont publish any `pointcloud` message.

---

Originally posted by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) with karma: 67 on 2015-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [david059](https://answers.ros.org/users/22144/david059/) on 2015-05-11**:
WOW! So quick! Thank you very much for your guidance! So now I understand what can be used for OpenNI and what cannot. But can I take it that the pointcloud can just only be generated by OpenNI which means I have to have devices you mentioned? Is there any other way I can get pointcloud with uabcam?

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-05-11**:
Yup I mentioned, lsd_slam and ORB_Slam you can get good pointcloud, but for very good pointcloud either use lsd_slam with global shutter camera with fish eye lens or Kinect/Asus Xiton with freenect/openNI2 package.

**Comment by [david059](https://answers.ros.org/users/22144/david059/) on 2015-05-11**:
I think you just really did me a great favor! Even though I can't find LSD_SLAM nor ORB_SLAM in http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php, I find them in github! I will try them right now and I hope this time I can make it. Thank you, KDROS!

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-05-11**:
Thanx, Yup It is not available in ROS, check this links [lsd_slam](http://vision.in.tum.de/research/lsdslam).
You can ask if you will be in trouble.

**Comment by [david059](https://answers.ros.org/users/22144/david059/) on 2015-05-12**:
Hey KDROS, after reading about what it says in github, I realize the problem you mentioned , LSD_SLAM indeed can not be used for live-pointcloud use in ROS. ButI think I find another way to get PointCloud2 data. By using [image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc?distro=indigo)

**Comment by [david059](https://answers.ros.org/users/22144/david059/) on 2015-05-12**:
I will talk in more detail in my answer below

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To obtain sensor_msgs/PointCloud or sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 data, I think there is an easy way to realize it. No matter what your camera_driver is, there will always have Image_raw data. I use PointGrey carema and usb camera, both drivers of them can get raw image whose format is sensor_msgs/Image. Next use image_proc http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc?distro=indigo we can get Image_rect [Image] which is the data format needed in the next step. I find depth_image_proc can produce PoindCloud or PointCloud2 data by using Image_rect. Here: http://wiki.ros.org/depth_image_proc. I think this is a way worthy of trying, even though I don't know what kind of image will finally get. I'm trying now, and I will update this question informing any one who see this question. Welcome everyone to come to discuss.

---

Originally posted by [david059](https://answers.ros.org/users/22144/david059/) with karma: 13 on 2015-05-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-05-12**:
Flow is good.. I will also try this, its very cheaper approach. Thanx.
But till now I am using lsd_slam and kinect and getting good result.

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-05-13**:
Is it working fine ?
In my case am getting error manager arg need to be set, I rectified this by giving true.. and there is no node/launch file for depth_image_proc. Tell me the detail execution process, it sounds interesting.
I was using this package earlier but that time also i was unable to solve

**Comment by [david059](https://answers.ros.org/users/22144/david059/) on 2015-05-13**:
I just get it through, you have to write a launch file according to the nodelet_plugins.xml file in depth_image_proc. You have to run a nodelet and here is the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet/Tutorials/Running%20a%20nodelet), I can get some thing in RVIZ, but still some trouble in ar_track

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-05-13**:
I run image_proc, it is running successfully but its not publishing any topic. are you getting this? did you change any thing in launch file except manager arg?

**Comment by [david059](https://answers.ros.org/users/22144/david059/) on 2015-05-13**:
if you are running a node, run this ROS_NAMESPACE=*my_camera* rosrun image_proc image_proc. my_camera is the relative name provided by your camera driver there will have topic shown in http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc?distro=indigo Nodes section.

**Comment by [david059](https://answers.ros.org/users/22144/david059/) on 2015-05-13**:
If you roslaunch a launch file you have to rectify the original launch file, assign specific arg value like args="load image_proc/debayer $(arg manager) $(arg bond)" you need replace $(arg manager) with standalone_nodelet, like tutorial in the [](http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet/Tutorials/Running%20a%20n

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-05-14**:
Main benefit of lsd_slam over this is that it fuses all pointcloud (like PCL) but in image_proc it is just publishing pointcloud for each image. which is easily doable by Kinect.